# Android gallery 3d effect

Tags: android

I am trying to give my gallery a 3D feel to instead of the standard look.  I have read about imageView.setCameraDistance(); but when I set it nothing happens and the gallery still looks the same with no changes.  can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Here is my code for the gallery.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setCameraDistance(2);

    }else{
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
    return imageView;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.